# What is the difference between a struct in a struct, and a named anonymous struct that is part of a surrounding struct?

Tags: c, struct, declaration

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct not_inner {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct outer {
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } x;
    
    struct not_inner y;
};

int main()
{
    struct outer O = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    //x.a = 5;
    

    printf("%d %d %d %d", O.x.a, O.x.b, O.y.a, O.y.b);

    return 0;
}
```

Mainly, I am intersted in what is the difference between x and y regarding:

- the c99 standard
- access speed
- scope

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by 'scope?'

Comment: you mean apart from one of them having a name?

Comment: y is made from a struct that is global, and x is a named anonymous struct local to the outer struct. So not_inner can be (mis)used, and x has a small scope and you can't access it with x.a (as I wrote in the commented-out code)

Comment: `x` is not anonymous, it is named `x`.  The type of `x` is anonymous, which makes it harder to have pointers to it, but that should be the only difference.

Comment: "what is the difference between x and y regarding:" "the c99 standard" Nothing.  "access speed" Nothing. "scope" Nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between a struct in a struct, and a named anonymous struct that is part of a surrounding struct?

"[N]amed anonymous struct" is a curious turn of phrase, but I take you to mean member `x` of `struct outer`.  I would call that a member whose type is an untagged structure type.  It is definitely not an *anonymous struct* -- that has a specific, more natural meaning, and a different significance.

> Mainly, I am intersted in what is the difference between x and y
> regarding:
>
> - the c99 standard

Both forms are equally conformant to C99 and all subsequent versions of C.

> - access speed

There is no reason to expect any difference in access speed arising from whether a structure type is tagged.  The structure tag has no runtime representation.

> - scope

Unless it has a `typedef` alias, an untagged structure type cannot be referenced outside the declaration in which it appears.  But that does not impair access to any objects declared with that type, nor to their members, nor does it prevent *compatible* types being declared.  You can do anything with your `outer.x` that you can do with your `outer.y`, but some things you might want to do would require more code for `x`.

Note well that the specific form you present for `x` is a bit unusual (albeit certainly not unknown), but variations along these lines are relatively common:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} untagged_struct;

struct outer2 {
    untagged_struct x;
    
    struct not_inner y;
};
```

The type of `outer2.x` is also an untagged structure type.  Having a `typedef` alias for that type solves substantially all of the issues that might make some operations on `outer.x` require more code than similar operations on `outer.y`.

As a matter of style, however, I personally prefer to avoid most uses of `typedef`, including in particular for structure types.  I would rather write (and see) `struct my_struct` than just `my_struct` or the like.

Answer (score 2):

Scope:

`x` and `y` only exist as members of a `struct outer` object.

`struct outer` and `struct not_inner` are scoped to the translation unit (.c file).

> [C99 §6.7.2.1¶7] The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit. [...]

---

Speed:

Types don't exist at run-time. Both `O.x.a` and `O.y.a` both directly access the member. So the details of the declaration has no effect on speed. Even if it did, you wouldn't find this in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a notion as a "named anonymous structure" in C.

The notion of anonymous structure is defined the following way (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 13 An unnamed member of structure type with no tag is called an
> anonymous structure;

In your program there is no anonymous structure.

Within the structure `struct outer`

```
struct outer {
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } x;
    
    struct not_inner y;
};
```

there is declared a data member of an unnamed structure (without the structure tag name). So opposite to the structure `struct not_inner` you can not refer to the unnamed structure specifier.

The tag names `outer` and `not_inner` have the file scope.

There is no difference in speed accessing data members of the unnamed structures and the structure `not_inner`.

Comment: Please note that the quoted part only exists in ISO C (C11/C17), not in C99. Anonymous structures were added in C11 (and are not present in the OP's code).